# inserting data to mysql using python QT and mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, qt5

I'm struggling to insert or retrive data from database I tried and I watched many tutorials but every time it stops in `cur.execute()`. i found problem is in the value like self.FirstNmae.text() funtion stop here

```py
def SignupFunction(self):
    try:
        
        connection = pymysql.connect(host=cr.host, user=cr.user, password=cr.password, database=cr.database)
        
        cur = connection.cursor()
        
        cur.execute("insert into users (FirstNmae , LastName, Email,Password , Confirm_Paswword ,Answer) value( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
            (
                self.FirstNmae.text(),
                self.LastName.text(),
                self.Email.text(),
                self.Password.text(),
                self.Confirm_Paswword.text(),
                self.Answer.text()
            ))
        
        connection.commit()
        
        connection.close()
        self.labelResult.setText("Data Inserted ")
    except Exception as e:
        self.labelResult.setText("Error Inserting Data")
```

Comment: Is it a SQL error or a Python error? What is the message?

Comment: there is  no message the the  program stop ruining when i clicked on register  when i chick i found that  it stop in  cur.excute()

Comment: Did you write FirstNmae everywhere? Maybe you used FirstName instead.

Comment: yes i write the same name in data base ,qt designer and in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello friend i'm not able  to comment so i will post  as answer from your code you are a new developer  , your function is good there are no problem in it i think that the problem is in you database look at the database if you are  missed something or you mess write attributes like  FirstNmae

Comment: yes you are right i make my id_user not null after i modified it  the function work thank you Sir